# Adding .gitignore and removing files that should have been ignored

Tags: android, git

I followed this link https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ to push my project to a repo. I noticed that I don't have a gitignore file and that files such as .idea and .iml have been added to the repo. How do I add a gitignore file and delete these from the repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add **.gitignore** file to your **project root** directory

Get .gitignore file for android from [Android.gitignore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Android.gitignore)
It contains **all possible ignore** files which should be ignored from android project

Then follow these **git commands** to remove files from git repository. **Local** files will **not** be deleted

```
 git rm --cached .idea
 git rm --cached project.iml
 git rm --cached <file_name>
```

**Remove** all the files you want to ignore
Then **add the changes** and **commit** it using following commands

```
 git add .
 git commit -m "ignoreable files ignored"
```

Then if you want to push those changes to **remote** just use

```
git push origin master
```

---

**Edit 1**

In case your remote branch has **new commits** and updated by other contributor you need to **fetch** it and **rebase** it before pushing

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master
```

So it will be **synced** with local branch

Comment: What files are not necessary? I know .gradle and .idea folders are not as well as any .iml files. What about the gradle folder or any of the gradle files?

Comment: Keep "gradle" folder it contains gradle wrapper.  Don't keep ".gradle" folder. Also checkout this file, has list of all unwanted files for android project https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Android.gitignore

Comment: Would it be the same to just go to my repo and delete it manually instead of through git commands? If so, do I need to pull in my project before pushing again?

Comment: You can delete it directly. It will work. But if you want to delete it from .git repository history you need to use git rm with --cached option

Comment: If i delete it from the repository history, and then I pull, will those files get deleted on my machine?

Comment: If you need to push changes just use push master it will get reflected on remote repo. If your remote files are changed then first fetch (not pull) the remote and apply rebase and push to remote

Comment: @GeraldTan Updated answer with Edit 1 section to show remote sync. BTW Consider upvoting and approving this answer if it helped :)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what fetch and rebase will do. How is this different than pull? Also, will the files that I deleted in the repo get deleted on my local machine if I pull?

Comment: @GeraldTan Use `git rm --cached <file_name> ` if you just want to delete it from repository and not local machine. Pull will directly pull code and merge into local code and may cause extra merge commit if remote is updated by someone else. So its recommended to use fetch and rebase to keep git clean :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.gitignore` file at the root of your git repository. In that, you can put as a new-line separated list, the regular expressions of the paths you want git to ignore while looking for changes in your repository.

So for example, your git repo root directory has the following sub directories that you want git to ignore,

`{git-root}/project/bin/debug`
`{git-root}/project/bin/release`

You can simply add `{git-root}/project/bin/` in your `.gitignore` if these two directories are the only ones in your `{git-root}/project/bin` sub-directory.

Similarly, if in your `{git-root}/project/bin` sub directory, you have another directory `tests` and you do not want to ignore that, then you will have to add
`{git-root}/project/bin/debug`
`{git-root}/project/bin/release`  
to your `.gitignore` file.

For an example, this is the `.gitignore` file of an android project I am working on. You can observe the syntax:

```
{project}/app/release/
{project}/app/debug/
{project}/api_objects/
{project}/.idea/caches/
{project}/api/
{project}/.idea/vcs.xml
{project}/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
```

After this, don't forget to add the `.gitignore` to your git repo using `git add .gitignore`.
You can do all this manually or through any of the Git desktop clients like `Sourcetree` or `Git Desktop`. It is easier to do this using the UI tools I listed.

Comment: How should the asker remove the files that have already been committed to the repository?  They're still in the repository even now that they're ignored.